# Como mascarar um input no HTML5?

Tags: html5, input

Por exemplo... Quero um `input` exclusivo para números de telefone. Ao digitar o DDD ele automaticamente recebe os parênteses: (xx). Ao digitar o restante dos números ele divida com um hífen, por exemplo: (xx)abcd-efgh. E nos casos de estados que receberam o nono dígito, (xx)9abcd-efgh.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer mascarar o que o usuário digita é isso?

Comment: Mais ou menos, tipo... Quando ele clicar no input já aparece os parenteses para colocar o ddd por exemplo, tem um type padrão para isso?

Comment: @Everton No caso você está querendo mascarar um `input`. Fiz uma edição na sua pergunta, alterando o título. Você pode [revertê-la](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/51109/revisions) caso não apresente melhorias.

Answer (score 17):

Você pode mascarar um campo utilizando:

> [JQuery Mask Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/) 
>   [Documentação](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

**Exemplo de uso:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#telefone').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
});
```

Ou no próprio html:

```
<input type="text" name="telefone" data-mask="(00) 0000-0000" data-mask-selectonfocus="true" />
```

Você também pode aplicar callback, em fim... há vários exemplos na documentação que se encaixam a sua necessidade..

> Para casos em que o estado possua o nono dígito, você pode utilizar a
>   mudança On-the-fly: Exemplo **retirado da documentação**, necessita apenas
>   a adaptação a sua necessidade:

```
var options =  {onKeyPress: function(cep, e, field, options){
  var masks = ['00000-000', '0-00-00-00'];
    mask = (cep.length>7) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
  $('.crazy_cep').mask(mask, options);
}};

$('.crazy_cep').mask('00000-000', options);
```

Ou a solução que o @Wallace forneceu nos comentários que seria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#telefone').mask('(00) 0000-0000#');
});
```

Ou também a seguinte expressão:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#telefone').mask('(00) 0000-00009');
});
```

Onde o 0 seria obrigatório e o 9 opcional;

@Wallace também citou a validação utilizando HTML5.

Comment: Para os casos onde existem o tal do "nono dígito", creio que se possa usar a expressão `(00) 0000-0000#`

Comment: Ou também a atualização da máscara On-the-fly, existe um exemplo da documentação fornecida; Vou editar a resposta para fornecer a solução também;

Answer (score 6):

O que você está querendo pode ser feito facilmente com [jQuery Mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

O seu uso se dá exatamente como o @RafaelWithoeft descrever em sua resposta.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name=telefone]').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
});
```

Quanto a fazer isso somente com o HTML5, o que você vai conseguir fazer no máximo é utilizar o atributo `pattern`. Porém este atributo não vai servir para o autopreenchimento, mas apenas para a validação do campo conforme o formato desejado.

Por exemplo, no caso de uma validação de um telefone:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\(\d{2}\)\d{4}-\d{4}" />
#exige que o campo seja preenchido com "(99)9999-9999"
```

Answer (score 4):

Para quem quiser uma solução que **não utiliza JQuery**:

```js
const tel = document.getElementById('tel') // Seletor do campo de telefone

tel.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => mascaraTelefone(e.target.value)) // Dispara quando digitado no campo
tel.addEventListener('change', (e) => mascaraTelefone(e.target.value)) // Dispara quando autocompletado o campo

const mascaraTelefone = (valor) => {
    valor = valor.replace(/\D/g, "")
    valor = valor.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g, "($1) $2")
    valor = valor.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/, "$1-$2")
    tel.value = valor // Insere o(s) valor(es) no campo
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" maxlength="15" pattern="\(\d{2}\)\s*\d{5}-\d{4}" required>
```