# Mascara no form somente em html e css

Tags: html, css, input, label

Estou iniciando em HTML/CSS e tentando criar máscara apenas nessas marcações (HTML/CSS) para os campos de meu formulário. Será possível ou devo usar JavaScript para a importação das mascaras?

```html
<label for="campo3">Data de Nascimento</label>
<input id="campo3" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: dd/mm/aaaa" data-mask="00/00/0000" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" name="customer['birthdate']">
```

Comment: você pode usar `type="date"` e o HTML faz uma máscara e validação

Comment: [Você pode encontrar sua resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51109/como-mascarar-um-input-no-html5)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam O problema do type="date" é que não tem suporte no IE. Me parece também que ele vai querer usar outras máscaras sem ser de datas.

Comment: Mascara acho que o CSS não faz, na verdade tenho certeza. O que vc pode fazer é usar os Type da forma correta e fazer Patterns para validar o campo com Required. Mas de máscara o máximo que vc consegue é usar o Placeholder mesmo... Pelo menos até onde sei

Comment: Além de "data", quais os tipos de máscara que vc vai precisar?

Comment: estes scripts devem ser executados no header ou no footer ? ou na pasta js do siste ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para os campos onde serão "datas", você poderia usar o atributo [`type="date"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data), mas ele não tem suporte no Internet Explorer e Safari, segundo a **[documentação no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data)**.

Apenas com CSS/HTML você não conseguirá criar máscaras nos campos. Esse tipo de manipulação só é possível através de script. O `placeholder` é indicado apenas para ilustrar ao usuário o formato ou tipo do dado a ser inserido.

Existem alguns *plugins* de máscara que você pode importar, mas você mesmo pode implementar com JavaScript puro sem a necessidade de importar nada. Veja uma simples função em JavaScript que formata os dados inseridos de acordo com o tipo informado no `oninput`:

```
function mascara(i,t){

   var v = i.value;

   if(isNaN(v[v.length-1])){
      i.value = v.substring(0, v.length-1);
      return;
   }

   if(t == "data"){
      i.setAttribute("maxlength", "10");
      if (v.length == 2 || v.length == 5) i.value += "/";
   }

   if(t == "cpf"){
      i.setAttribute("maxlength", "14");
      if (v.length == 3 || v.length == 7) i.value += ".";
      if (v.length == 11) i.value += "-";
   }

   if(t == "cnpj"){
      i.setAttribute("maxlength", "18");
      if (v.length == 2 || v.length == 6) i.value += ".";
      if (v.length == 10) i.value += "/";
      if (v.length == 15) i.value += "-";
   }
}
```

A parte abaixo impede que sejam inseridos outro tipo de caractere que não seja número:

```
if(isNaN(v[v.length-1])){
   i.value = v.substring(0, v.length-1);
   return;
}
```

No evento `oninput` você envia para a função o elemento e o tipo de dado a ser formatado:

```
oninput="mascara(this, 'data')"
oninput="mascara(this, 'cpf')"
oninput="mascara(this, 'cnpj')"
```

E a própria função já delimita o número de caracteres que será permitido no campo:

```
i.setAttribute("maxlength", "14"); // para CPF
```

**Veja em funcionamento:**

```js
function mascara(i,t){
   
   var v = i.value;
   
   if(isNaN(v[v.length-1])){
      i.value = v.substring(0, v.length-1);
      return;
   }
   
   if(t == "data"){
      i.setAttribute("maxlength", "10");
      if (v.length == 2 || v.length == 5) i.value += "/";
   }

   if(t == "cpf"){
      i.setAttribute("maxlength", "14");
      if (v.length == 3 || v.length == 7) i.value += ".";
      if (v.length == 11) i.value += "-";
   }

   if(t == "cnpj"){
      i.setAttribute("maxlength", "18");
      if (v.length == 2 || v.length == 6) i.value += ".";
      if (v.length == 10) i.value += "/";
      if (v.length == 15) i.value += "-";
   }

   if(t == "cep"){
      i.setAttribute("maxlength", "9");
      if (v.length == 5) i.value += "-";
   }

   if(t == "tel"){
      if(v[0] == 9){
         i.setAttribute("maxlength", "10");
         if (v.length == 5) i.value += "-";
      }else{
         i.setAttribute("maxlength", "9");
         if (v.length == 4) i.value += "-";
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<label for="campo3">Data de Nascimento</label>
<input oninput="mascara(this, 'data')" id="campo3" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: dd/mm/aaaa" autocomplete="off" name="customer['birthdate']">
<br>
<label for="campo4">CPF</label>
<input oninput="mascara(this, 'cpf')" id="campo4" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: xxx.xxx.xxx-xx" autocomplete="off" name="customer['cpf']">
<br>
<label for="campo5">CNPJ</label>
<input oninput="mascara(this, 'cnpj')" id="campo5" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: xx.xxx.xxx/xxxx-xx" autocomplete="off" name="customer['cnpj']">
<br>
<label for="campo6">CEP</label>
<input oninput="mascara(this, 'cep')" id="campo6" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: xxxxx-xxx" autocomplete="off" name="customer['cep']">
<br>
<label for="campo7">Telefone</label>
<input oninput="mascara(this, 'tel')" id="campo7" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: xxxxx-xxxx" autocomplete="off" name="customer['tel']">
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela perfeita explicação. Apenas uma dúvida bem ignorante, todo esse script eu coloco junto ao html nos forms ou crio um scritp separado com a função? Obrigado.

Comment: Vc coloca entre as tags <script></script>

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Como ficaria se eu quisesse colocar máscaras para CEP e telefone/celular? Abcs.

Comment: Vou fazer aqui e incluir na resposta... só um instante

Comment: Obrigado! Sei nem como lhe agradecer. Abcs

Comment: Resposta atualizada. QQ problema pode avisar.

Comment: Se alguém quiser com DDD, eu fiz a alteração

Answer (score 1):

Caso alguém queira a mascara com DDD (xx) xxxx-xxxx:

```
if(t === "tel"){
  if (v.length === 1) i.value = "(" + i.value;
  if (v.length === 3) i.value += ") ";
  if(v[5] == 9){
     i.setAttribute("maxlength", "15");
     if (v.length === 10) i.value += "-";
  }else{
     i.setAttribute("maxlength", "14");
     if (v.length === 9) i.value += "-";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
  <title>Kaio Maravilhoso</title>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>
   function mascaraData(){

   var data = document.getElementById('txtData').value;
   if(data.length==2){
    document.getElementById('txtData').value = data +'/';
     }
   else if (data.length==5){
    document.getElementById('txtData').value = data +'/';
   }
}

   function mascaraRg(){

   var rg= document.getElementById('txtRg').value;
   if(rg.length==2){
    document.getElementById('txtRg').value = rg +'.';
     }
   else if (rg.length==6){
    document.getElementById('txtRg').value = rg +'.';
   }
   else if (rg.length==9){
    document.getElementById('txtRg').value = rg +'-';
   }
}

   function mascaraTelefone(){

   var telefone= document.getElementById('txtTelefone').value;
   if(telefone.length==1){
    document.getElementById('txtTelefone').value ='(' + telefone;
     }
   else if (telefone.length==3){
    document.getElementById('txtTelefone').value = telefone +')';
   }

   else if (telefone.length==8){
    document.getElementById('txtTelefone').value = telefone +'-';
   }
}

   function mascaraCel(){

   var celular= document.getElementById('txtCel').value;
   if(celular.length==1){
    document.getElementById('txtCel').value ='(' + celular;
     }
   else if (celular.length==3){
    document.getElementById('txtCel').value = celular +')';
   }
   else if (celular.length==9){
    document.getElementById('txtCel').value = celular +'-';
   }
}




   function mascaraCpf(){
   var cpf = document.getElementById('txtCpf').value;
    if(cpf.length==3){
     document.getElementById('txtCpf').value = cpf +'.';
}
    else if(cpf.length==7){
     document.getElementById('txtCpf').value = cpf +'.';
}
    else if (cpf.length==11){
     document.getElementById('txtCpf').value = cpf +'-';
}    
}  

function checarEmail(){

   var email= document.getElementById('txtEmail').value;
   if(email==""||email.indexOf('@')==-1||email.indexOf('.')==-1){

    alert("Por favor Insira um E-mail valido");

}
}

function limpa_formulário_cep() {

            document.getElementById('txtRua').value=("");
            document.getElementById('txtBairro').value=("");
            document.getElementById('txtCidade').value=("");
            document.getElementById('txtUf').value=("");
    }
 function meu_callback(conteudo) {
        if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
            //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
            document.getElementById('txtRua').value=(conteudo.logradouro);
            document.getElementById('txtBairro').value=(conteudo.bairro);
            document.getElementById('txtCidade').value=(conteudo.localidade);
            document.getElementById('txtUf').value=(conteudo.uf);

        } 
        else {

            limpa_formulário_cep();
            alert("CEP não encontrado.");
        }
    }

 function mascaraCep(){
   var cep = document.getElementById('txtCep').value;
    if(cep.length==5){
     document.getElementById('txtCep').value = cep +'-';
}
}
 function pesquisacep(valor) {


        var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');


        if (cep != "") {


            var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;


            if(validacep.test(cep)) {

                //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta webservice.
                document.getElementById('txtRua').value="...";
                document.getElementById('txtBairro').value="...";
                document.getElementById('txtCidade').value="...";
                document.getElementById('txtUf').value="...";



                var script = document.createElement('script');


                script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/?callback=meu_callback';


                document.body.appendChild(script);

            } 
            else {

                limpa_formulário_cep();
                alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
            }
        }
        else {

            limpa_formulário_cep();
        }
    };
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Cadastro</h1>
  <hr />


  <form method="get class "form-group">

  <div class="row">


  <div class ="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
    Nome:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id="txtNome"  maxlength="10"/> 
  </div>
  <div class = "row">
  <div class ="col-md-4">
   <div class="form-group">
    Data:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id="txtData" onkeypress="mascaraData()" maxlength="10"/> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class ="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    CPF:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtCpf" onkeypress="mascaraCpf()" maxlength="14"/>

  </div>
  </div>
  <div class ="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    RG:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtRg" onkeypress="mascaraRg()" maxlength="12"/>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    Telefone:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtTelefone" onkeypress="mascaraTelefone()" maxlength="13"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    Celular:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtCel" onkeypress="mascaraCel()" maxlength="14"/>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    Cep:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtCep" onblur="pesquisacep(this.value)" onkeypress="mascaraCep()"/>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    Cidade:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtCidade"/>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    Bairro:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtBairro"/>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    Rua:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtRua"/>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    Uf:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtUf"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    Email:<input type="text" class= "form-control" id ="txtEmail" onblur="checarEmail();"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   Selecione
   <select class ="form-control">
    <option></option>
    <option>opção 1</option>
    <option>opção 2</option>
    <option>opção 3</option>
    <option>opção 4</option>
   </select>
  </div>

  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
  value="enviar"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  </div>
</div>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seria interessante você incluir uma breve descrição da sua abordagem.

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém queira, fiz esta máscara para CPF com poucas linhas de javascript. O atributo `onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"` direto no campo html é 
o que faz permitir apenas números.

O eventListener "input" retorna as validações sempre que um número é digitado no campo.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        let a = document.getElementById('campo');
        
        a.addEventListener("input", () => {
            let arr = a.value.split('');
            
            if(arr.length > 3 && arr[3] != "."){
                arr.splice(3,0,'.');
            }

            if(arr.length > 7 && arr[7] != "."){
                arr.splice(7,0,'.');
            }

            if(arr.length > 11 && arr[11] != "-"){
                arr.splice(11,0,'-');
            }

            a.value = arr.join('');
        });
    });
```

```html
 <input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" maxlength="14" name="" placeholder="Máscara CPF" id="campo">
```