# onChange no jQuery Input Mask não funciona

Tags: html, jquery, react

Tenho um componente React para cadastro de usuários, em alguns dos campos eu adicionei uma mascara Jquery, mas desde que adicionei a mascara, parou de funcionar o comando onChange (apenas nos campos com a mascara)

um dos campos é este:

```
<input type="text" className="form-control nascimento-cliente" id="nascimento"  name="nascimento" onChange = {(event) => this.onChange(event.target) } />
```

A função que o onChange está chamando:

```
onChange(target) {
    const change = {};
    change[target.name] = target.value;
    this.setState(change);
}
```

Se eu remover a mascara tudo funciona, mas em alguns campos a mascara é essencial

Comment: Provavelmente está dando algum conflito de Js no script.

Comment: Existe alguma maneira simples de verificar isso?

Comment: Se no console não mostrar nada, cara vai ser bem difícil descobrir, isto é um grande problema com estes novos frameworks de Js como Angular, React etc... Para vc conseguir utilizar jQuery com estes frameworks sem dar nenhum tipo de conflito é bem complicado, por isso até, o pessoal **recomenda** não utilizar jQuery.

Comment: Entendi.. então acho melhor eu utilizar um componente React para colocar as mascara.
Obrigado

Comment: Use uma máscara em JS puro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/280783/8063

Comment: Utilize esta máscara que o DVD fez, vai servir aí para vc.

Comment: Valeu @dvd, eu estou em outro projeto mais urgente agora, mas assim que terminar já testo essa solução

Comment: Tranquilo. QQ coisa é só chamar.

Comment: @dvd funcionou que é uma beleza!!! só tive que mudar o formato do telefone pra ter DDD, mas já veio praticamente pronto

Comment: Legal. Sucesso aí.

Comment: Posta uma resposta de como vc fez caso sirva pra alguém no futuro.

Comment: Postei no tópico que você criou pt.stackoverflow.com/a/280783/8063