# Regex no pattern do input sempre válida

Tags: javascript, html5, regex, input

Tenho um formulário de contanto em que o visitante pode inserir o telefone e estou tentando válidar usando o atributo pattern do input usando uma expressão regular que encontrei em um post no [Medium](https://medium.com/@mariojr.rcosta/php-dica-r%C3%A1pida-validando-n%C3%BAmeros-de-telefone-com-regex-e-preg-match-802723dbc2e9):

```
^(?:(?:\+|00)?(55)\s?)?(?:\(?([0-0]?[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1})\)?\s?)??(?:((?:9\d|[2-9])\d{3}\-?\d{4}))$
```

Eu testei a expressão usando o regex101, como pode ser visto no link abaixo, e funciona. Inclusive, estou usando a mesma expressão para válidar o telefone no backend.

https://regex101.com/r/10yNjW/1

O problema é que por algum motivo, que não consigo entender, não está funcionando no meu site, isto é, qualquer valor inserido no campo onde deveria ser o telefone é dado como válido.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="phone">Seu telefone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" pattern="^(?:(?:\+|00)?(55)\s?)?(?:\(?([0-0]?[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1})\)?\s?)??(?:((?:9\d|[2-9])\d{3}\-?\d{4}))$">

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Essa expressão regular é usada para "buscar", existindo ou não, não é para ser "estrita", ou seja, no exemplo que o autor no medium passou deixou evidente que serve para buscar em textos o numero, se não existir não retorna nada, no seu caso a expressão regular tem que ser mais simples e estrita, o bom seria mesmo você aplicar um esquema de mascara para padronizar o telefone, sugestões: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51109/3635

Comment: Só pra constar, quem escreveu esse artigo do Medium não parece saber muito bem o que está fazendo. Primeiro ele remove os parênteses, mas na regex ele coloca `\(?` e `\)?` (que verifica se tem parênteses opcionais - o que é desnecessário, uma vez que ele remove todos os parênteses na linha anterior). Sem contar o trecho `[0-0]?[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}` (que eu comento na [resposta abaixo](/a/477556/112052) como simplificar), que me parece típico de quem copiou-colou sem entender (ou tentou fazer sem saber muito o que estava fazendo). Claro que posso estar enganado, mas é a impressão que tive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resposta curta

O problema está no hífen, no trecho final (`\d{3}\-?\d{4}`). Em vez de `\-`, coloque simplesmente `-` (ou seja, `\d{3}-?\d{4}`).

---

### Resposta longa

> *Mas por que funcionou no regex101?*

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern), a regex que está no atributo `pattern` é compilada com a [*flag* `u` (Unicode)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) (para mais detalhes sobre esta *flag*, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499630/112052)). E [no modo Unicode o hífen não pode ser precedido por `\`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39899720) (exceto se estiver em uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)). Sendo assim, da forma que está, a regex se torna inválida, e quando a regex não é válida, o atributo `pattern` é ignorado (e por isso ele acaba aceitando qualquer coisa).

Só funcionou no regex101 porque lá não foi usado o modo Unicode. Veja a diferença:

```js
// sem a flag u - funciona
let semUnicode = /\d\-\d/;
console.log('válido:', semUnicode);

// com a flag u - erro
let comUnicode = /\d\-\d/u;
console.log('Não vai imprimir esta mensagem porque dá erro na linha acima');
```

Tanto que se você setar a *flag* `u` no regex101 (no canto superior direito, logo depois do campo onde você digita a regex, no ícone da "bandeirinha"), a regex também dá erro ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/10yNjW/2)). Neste caso só funciona se tirarmos a `\` antes do hífen ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/10yNjW/3)).

Obs: como já dito, o hífen só deve ser escapado com `\` em lugares onde ele tem significado especial (ou seja, dentro de colchetes, que demarcam uma classe de caracteres - por exemplo: `[a-z]` é o intervalo entre "a" e "z" (o hífen serve para denotar um intervalo), e `[a\-z]` é "a letra `a`, ou um hífen, ou a letra `z`").

---

Também tem outras melhorias para fazer nesta regex. Como você só quer validar, não precisa dos parênteses para criar os [grupos de captura](http://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (só preciso manter aqueles que servem para agrupar alguns trechos da expressão).

E o trecho `[0-0]?[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}` dá para ser simplificado:

- `[0-0]` significa "um caractere entre 0 e 0", ou seja, pode trocar pelo próprio `0`
- `[0-9]{1}` significa "uma ocorrência de um dígito de 0 a 9", e como isso aparece duas vezes seguidas, pode ser trocado para `\d{2}` (duas ocorrências de um dígito de 0 a 9)

  - de forma geral, usar `{1}` nunca é necessário, pois `(qualquer coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer coisa)`

Então ficaria assim:

```js
const campo = document.querySelector('#phone');
campo.addEventListener('input', () => {
    campo.setCustomValidity('');
    campo.checkValidity();
});
campo.addEventListener('invalid', () => {
    campo.setCustomValidity('O campo deve ser um telefone válido');
});
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="phone">Seu telefone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"
     pattern="^(?:(?:\+|00)?55\s?)?(?:\(?(0?\d{2})\)?\s?)??(?:9\d|[2-9])\d{3}-?\d{4}$">

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Claro que ainda dá para melhorar mais, pois a regex aceita `00` como DDD (talvez devesse ser `[1-9]{2}`, pois atualmente [nenhum DDD possui o dígito zero](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discagem_direta_a_dist%C3%A2ncia#Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_DDD_brasileiros_por_estado,_com_as_principais_cidades_e_regi%C3%B5es)). Se quiser, pode dar uma olhada [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46672/112052), que tem várias outras opções.

---

Mas como [já disseram nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/477536/regex-no-pattern-do-input-sempre-v%C3%A1lida#comment895513_477536), talvez seja melhor o campo aceitar apenas números e você aplica uma máscara para facilitar o preenchimento por parte dos usuários. Acho que ficaria melhor do que aceitar vários formatos diferentes (pense na manutenção deste código, não ficou uma regex fácil de entender e manter).