# Quantificador "{,2}" para pegar no máximo 2 caracteres não funciona no atributo pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Peguei um exercício [daqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern4) com o código a seguir, que aceita, no mínimo, 2 caracteres depois do ponto:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Fiz uma modificação ao colocar `{,2}`. Nesse caso, ele deveria aceitar, no máximo, 2 caracteres depois do ponto, certo? Por que ele está aceitando mais de 2?
Como eu deveria fazer para ele aceitar até 2?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme dito na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) (e também explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/477536/112052)), a regex que está no atributo `pattern` é compilada com a [*flag* `u`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags) (tem mais detalhes sobre esta *flag* [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499630/112052)).

O que acontece é que quando esta *flag* está habilitada, a sintaxe da regex se torna mais restrita e passa a não aceitar determinados padrões. Veja a diferença:

```js
// sem flag "u", OK
let r1 = /[a-z]{,2}/;
console.log('regex ok', r1);

// com flag "u", erro (Incomplete quantifier)
let r2 = /[a-z]{,2}/u;
console.log('não será impresso, pois dá erro na linha acima', r2);
```

Repare que a primeira regex não dá erro, mas a segunda sim. A presença da *flag* `u` faz com que a sintaxe se torne mais restrita e não aceite o quantificador sem o valor inicial (dá um erro: "*Incomplete quantifier*"). E quando a regex é inválida, o atributo `pattern` é ignorado.

Para corrigir, você deve indicar explicitamente que o valor mínimo é zero:

```js
// indicar o valor mínimo igual a zero
let r = /[a-z]{0,2}/u;
console.log('regex OK', r);
```

---

Além disso, mesmo que `{,2}` não desse erro, ainda sim não iria funcionar da forma que você espera. Isso porque ele não é interpretado como um quantificador, e sim como literalmente o caractere `{`, seguido de vírgula, seguido de `2`, seguido de `}`. Veja:

```js
let r = /[a-z]{,2}/;

// no máximo 2 letras (não funciona)
console.log(r.test('a')); // false

// porque a regex na verdade é "uma letra, seguida de {,2}"
console.log(r.test('a{,2}')); // true
```

Ou seja, a solução para aceitar no máximo 2 caracteres é de fato colocar o zero:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email"
   pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{0,2}$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Vale lembrar que em algumas linguagens (como Python e Ruby, por exemplo) o `{,2}` funciona (significa "no máximo 2 ocorrências"). Na dúvida, eu diria para sempre usar `{0,2}`, que é mais garantido que funcione em todas...